# How to Limit the CPU usage for a process and its children whether there is another process demanding resources or not

Tags: 12.04, performance, cpu, cpu-load

I was thinking about using CPUlimit to limit process CPU usage, but I am aiming to apply the same percentage of usage for its child processes too automatically.

Is there something that can limits the CPU usage for a process and its children whether there is or there is not another process needing resources at the same time?

cgroup cpu.shares limits only when there is another process needing the resources consumed by a previous process. What I'm looking for is something like `sudo cpulimit -p 1234 -l 20` so the limit on cpu usage doesn't consider whether there is another process or not demanding the used resources.

This was applied to the parent process (pid =1234) but not its children.

Comment: Have a look at this: [Cpulimit](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-limit-cpu-usage-of-a-process-with-cpulimit-debian-ubuntu)

Comment: yes thank u , i read it ,but excuse me  ı didnt get what ıs the new thing u want to tell me , i am beginner

Comment: I'm not sure but if you look at `pstree -p` you can see the processes in a tree kind of way... now if you take the first PID and limit the cpu the "children PIDs" should automatically take over the cpu limit? But as mentioned i'm not sure.

Comment: well actually i am not sure too but i can tell that by using it i found that the child process of the parent process on gnome-system-monitor exceeds the limits which i specified

Comment: Well I didn't read your post thoroughly... I search a bit and found this [LINK](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=992706). Hope this helps :)

Comment: yes thank u it is very useful but actually i want to specify one my own which one i want to limit and which one not and with varying ration of limitation not for 20% for all running process as mentioned

Comment: Easily Change ‘CPU Affinity’ in Ubuntu using ‘procexp’ http://www.hecticgeek.com/2013/03/change-cpu-affinity-ubuntu-procexp/

Comment: Well Sir looks like you beat me to it... :D just wanted to post that myself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link may help  [Set maximum CPU consumption in percentage by any process](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=992706)
  searched by : [MrSeed](https://askubuntu.com/users/152011/mrseed)

this script may help too , any any one wants to enter suggestions on this script to enhance it , it will be my pleasure

```
       #!/bin/bash -xv

read -p "Which program u want to limit its processes?" ProgrameName
read -p "Which limitation percentage u want for it ?" limitationPercentage  
read -p "Period to be sleep " sleepInterval 
dataFile="/home/ahmedubuntu/Desktop/.file.txt"
separator="######"
trap "echo \"\" > $dataFile"  SIGINT SIGTERM SIGHUP
########################################################
if [ -e $dataFile ]; then
  echo "File $dataFile already exists!"
  echo -e "" > $dataFile
else
  echo >> $dataFile
fi 
echo -e "$ProgrameName \n $limitationPercentage \n" >> $dataFile
getAllPIDRunUnderThisProgram=$( ps -e | grep "$ProgrameName" | awk '{print $1;}')
echo -e "${getAllPIDRunUnderThisProgram[@]}  \n $separator \n" >> $dataFile
for i in $getAllPIDRunUnderThisProgram
   do
    gnomeTab+=( --tab -e "cpulimit -p $i -l $limitationPercentage ")  
   done
gnome-terminal "${gnomeTab[@]}"
#echo gnome-terminal "${gnomeTab[@]}"
########################################################
while sleep $sleepInterval
do
i=0
while read line
do
if [ -n "$line" ] && ["$line" != "separator"] 
then
programeNameAndPID[i]=$line
((i++))
elif [["$line" == "separator"]] ; then
getAllPIDRunUnderThisProgram=$( ps -e | grep "$programeNameAndPID[0]" | awk '{print $1;}')
if [${#getAllPIDRunUnderThisProgram[*]} -gt ${#programeNameAndPID[*]}-2  ]
then
unset gnomeTab
newProcessNumber=${#getAllPIDRunUnderThisProgram[*]}-${#programeNameAndPID[*]}-2
index=${#getAllPIDRunUnderThisProgram[*]}-1
for (( c=$newProcessNumber ; c > 0 ; c-- ))
do
gnomeTab+=( --tab -e "cpulimit -p $getAllPIDRunUnderThisProgram[$index] -l $programeNameAndPID[1] ") 
((index--)) 
done
gnome-terminal "${gnomeTab[@]}"
fi
i=0
unset programeNameAndPID
fi
done < $dataFile
done
```

and by adding `nice -10` will work well with no need to sudo and password